# Align checkmark at bottom right of heatmap cell

Tags: reactjs, heatmap, echarts, apache-echarts

I am using ECharts specifically heatmap. The structure of heatmap data is `[{x, y, label: "abc", confirmed: true/false}, ...]`. If confirmed is true, I want to display a checkmark at the bottom right of cell. I have tried, but the checkmark is shown at the right of label however I want it at bottom right of the cell... wasn't successful. Please help. Link to [Echart- Heatmap StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9kha3t?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Findex.js)

Comment: I think it's possible to display both label and checkmark at the bottom right of the cell but I'm not sure it's possible to use two labels in one cell. If it's possible, you can separate the label and checkmark into two individual labels and display the position you want.

Comment: You can format the label string to push the checkmark to the bottom right: `confirmed ? '\n\n\n\n\n\n                                                     {checkmark|}' : ''}`;`